# Idiomatic way to use not in a ruby conditional (alternative to elsunless)

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, control-flow

I have the following logic:

```
if something == 'some string'
  somevar1 = 'some extra extra extra extra extra extra long string'
elsif !somevar
  somevar1 = 'a much longer string a much longer string'
  somevar2 = 'some very very very long string'
end
```

Now my problem is that the second check in the conditional appears to not be idiomatic according to documentation i have read.

However, I have to perform the first check in the conditional.

Everything I read states to use 'unless' however an else in unless is not good practice. So I am trying to look for what is the perfect solution here.

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Would `elsif somevar.nil?` work?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom unless `somevar == false` e.g. `false.nil? #=> false`. I am not sure where the concern is `!` means not if you prefer you could use `not(somevar)` but I have never actually seen this used in practice.

Comment: Thanks phil.. I am used to using not due to my python bg, but I think == false, and false.nil? or exactly what I was looking for. Every ruby idiom I have seen says not to use !value so I was trying to find out the ruby way to handle this. Thank you!

Comment: @user2152283 Can you share this site that says `!value` is bad?  I can see getting deeply into double negatives such as `unless !value` isn't a good idea, but I can't see what's wrong with `elsif !somevar` if that makes the most sense.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyIdioms is the link. Please see testing for truth values. I have seen this in a few books as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always had the same question, but I will dump what I think.

Regarding the use of `unless` with `else`, the bad practice is this:

```
unless condition
  # stuff1
else
  # stuff2
end
```

This is a bad practice because, as you might guess, you can write it in a better, more logically reasonable and clear way:

```
if condition
  stuff2
else
  stuff1
end
```

Better, right?

However, in a situation like yours, you just cannot flip the conditions. So if you want to use `unless`, you will be using it like so:

```
if something == 'some string'
  somevar1 = 'some extra extra extra extra extra extra long string'
else
  unless somevar
    somevar1 = 'a much longer string a much longer string'
    somevar2 = 'some very very very long string'
  end
end
```

Which is readable and logically reasonable.

Still, if you have a clear idea about the type of `somevar` and when it becomes *false*, you have better stick with the `somevar.false?` like method. Of course there's no such `false?` method for all objects as far as I know, so you might like to use `nil?` or/and something similar.

```
if something == 'some string'
  somevar1 = 'some extra extra extra extra extra extra long string'
elsif somevar.nil?
  somevar1 = 'a much longer string a much longer string'
  somevar2 = 'some very very very long string'
end
```

For a string, for example, you could add a `.empty?` check if it suites you:

```
if something == 'some string'
  somevar1 = 'some extra extra extra extra extra extra long string'
elsif somevar.nil? or somevar.empty?
  somevar1 = 'a much longer string a much longer string'
  somevar2 = 'some very very very long string'
end
```

And, of course, you should consider the use of `!=` when you want specific type of checks, not just the "if not" type.